# How to compile multiple Fortran 90 files with Makefile using gfortran on Windows 10?

Tags: compilation, fortran, 64-bit, gfortran

When I compile Fortran 90 with Makefile, I used command lines below.

```
   # Ubuntu gfortran compiler tested with 4.6 and higher
    ifeq "$(FC_ENV)" "gfortran-6"
    LAPK_PATH = /usr
    # define the lapack libraries
    LIBLAPACK = -L$(LAPK_PATH)/lib -llapack -lblas
    endif

    NCDF_PATH = /opt/netcdf4-intel
    LAPK_PATH = /usr

    # define netcdf libraries and include files
    LIBNETCDF = -L$(NCDF_PATH)/lib -lnetcdff
    INCNETCDF = -I$(NCDF_PATH)/include
```

Now I want to know how to compile multiple files with Makefile using gfortran on Windows 10. Does Anybody know how to install NetCDF and Lapack library and set this text file?

I tried to use MinGW64 and intel Visual Fortran. But I don't know how to compile it.

Comment: Welcome. Please take the tour. Use tag [tag:fortran] to get more attention. How did you try to *"MinGW64 and intel Visual Fortran"*? Why do you use tag `gfortran`? Did you use it at all or not?

Comment: I looked at this site with Fortran. But I couldn't find useful information. 
I want to compile "https://github.com/NCAR/summa/tree/sopron_2018". 
I succeeded to compile this code on ubuntu os. Now I want to compile this on window10. I'm ok whatever I use MinGW64 and Visual Fortran. Last week I tried these two compilers, but there were errors. Also, I'm not good at Fortran compilation, especially on the window. Could you help me step by step if you possible?

Comment: Please do take the [tour], it is really importnt. Never say there are errors. Say which errors are there and copy the error messages. Also show the code. See also [ask] and [mcve].